# How to print only one element?

Tags: python

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = []
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        s.append(f'{name}, {score}')

s.remove(max(s))
print(s(f'{name}'))
```

I am trying to print just the name but it's showing an `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`. How do I print just the name of the runner-up without the single quote?

Comment: First you have to sort the list so that the winner is at first (or last) position (which would be hard because of the way you store the entries, better store tuples with score first). Then you can retrieve the runner-up from the list.

Comment: What do you think `print(s(f'{name}'))` is doing? `s(...)` is trying to call `s` (a `list`) as if it were a function. I haven't the foggiest notion what you were intending to do.

Comment: In the last string you don't call s(element). You can only call s[index], where index is an integer number.

Comment: Also, if you want to store and use `name` and `score` separately, store them as a `tuple` (`s.append((name, score))`), and defer conversion to string until you *need* it as a string. Makes the `list` *much* more programmatically useful to not dump it all in a string that would need to be parsed to extract partial information from it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors in the code provided. Here's a corrected version:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = []
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        s.append((name, score))  # Use a tuple instead of a string to store name and score.

    s.remove(max(s, key=lambda x: x[1]))  # Remove the tuple with the highest score.

    for name, _ in s:  # Loop through remaining tuples and print only the name.
        print(name)
```

1.Instead of storing name and score as a formatted string in the list s, we store them as a tuple using the syntax (name, score). This makes it easier to manipulate later on.

2. List item To remove the tuple with the highest score, we use the max() function with a key argument that tells it to compare tuples based on their second element (i.e., the score). We also need to unpack the tuple returned by max() and call remove() on the list s to remove it.

Finally, we loop through the remaining tuples in s and print only the name by unpacking each tuple and using _ to ignore the second element (i.e., the score).

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring because you are trying to call the list s as a function by using parentheses () instead of accessing an element in the list by using square brackets [].

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
s = []
for _ in range(int(input())):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())
    s.append((name, score))

s.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

second_highest_score = s[1][1]

runner_up_names = [x[0] for x in s if x[1] == second_highest_score]

for name in runner_up_names:
    print(name)
```

Comment: Made an error while reading the question. I am trying to find the min on the list. I modified your code a little bit but It would only print the number now and not the name.                             if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = []
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        s.append(f'{name}, {score}')

runner_up = s[1].split(',')
print(min(runner_up))

Comment: I understand you. I have edit the code, check now and if it works, please mark the question as answer

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to index a list with a string, and also using the wrong brackets. A list is always indexed with `[]`, not `()`, and inside those brackets you must always have a number, not a string. What you might be looking for is a dictionary, which associates a key (in you case a name) to a score, that you can then access by that name

[Read more here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict)

Your code should look like this:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = dict()
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        s[name] = score

# exercise for op s.remove(max(s))
print(s[name])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your list and second last member will always be the runner up.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = []
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        s.append(f'{name}, {score}')
s=sorted(s)
print(sorted(s)[-2].split(',')[0])  # this will always be the name of runner up no matter how many members are there in the list
```